# Assign custom attribute values to grid collection

Tags: magento2

I have a created a custom grid in admin ,

I want to assign custom attributes from customer to one of the column in the grid , I can get the value of attribute from customer repository but how can I pass it  to collection?

Any help appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by joining my collection with `customer_entity_varchar` table

```
 $customerEav = $collection->getTable('customer_entity_varchar');

 $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('customereav'=>$customerEav),
        '`order`.customer_id = customereav.entity_id AND customereav.attribute_id=214',
        ['custom_attribute' => 'customereav.value']);
```

hope this helps you as well.

Thank You.